# How to render/blit text in pygame for good performance

Tags: python, pygame, render, blit

I am working on a small game (as a hobby) using Pygame. Before this I never worked on graphical interfaces and I am encountering some performance issues. Even in the options menu the FPS seem to be capped at around 110, which maybe doesn't sound that bad, but considering it is just a black screen with some text on it the FPS definitely should be higher. This is the code for one of the textboxes:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 180)
color = (0,60,20)
screen.blit(font.render("Title", False, color), (480,0))
```

The options menu is nothing but around 15 of those textboxes and this already causes FPS issues. Is something wrong with how I am rendering or blitting the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not create the `pygame.font.Font` object in every frame and do not render the text in every frame. Create the text *Surface* once at the begin of the program or in the constructor (`__init__`) of a class. Just `blit` the text *Surface* in every frame:

At initialization:

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 180)
color = (0,60,20)
text_surface = font.render("Title", False, color)
```

Once per frame:

```py
screen.blit(text_surface, (480,0))
```

If the text is dynamic, it cannot even be pre-rendered. However, the most time-consuming is to create the [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) object. At the very least, you should avoid creating the font in every frame.
In a typical application you don't need all permutations of fonts and font sizes. You just need a couple of different `font` objects. Create a number of fonts at the beginning of the application and use them when rendering the text. For Instance:

```py
fontComic40  = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 40)
fontComic180 = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 180)
# [...]
```

Comment: wow, just creating the font object at the start of the program made the fps go from 110 to 250, and I haven't even changed anything with the rendering yet. Thx for the help!